# SQLite query doesn't work as expected

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem with an SQLite Query and can't figure it out. These are my table:

```
CREATE TABLE Exercise 
(
 e_id int auto_increment primary key, 
 name varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE PersonalList 
(
 p_id int auto_increment primary key, 
 name varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Exercise_Personal_List 
(
 e_id_m int auto_increment primary key, 
 p_id_m int
);


INSERT INTO Exercise
(e_id, name)
VALUES
('1', 'exercise1'),
('2', 'exercise2'),
('3', 'exercise3'),
('4', 'exercise4'),
('5', 'exercise5'),
('6', 'exercise6');

INSERT INTO PersonalList
(p_id, name)
VALUES
('1', 'list1'),
('2', 'list2'),
('3', 'list3');

INSERT INTO Exercise_Personal_List
(e_id_m, p_id_m)
VALUES
('2', '1'),
('4', '1'),
('6', '1'),
('1', '2');
```

- Exercise table: a collection of exercises
- PersonalList table: a collection of list
- Exercise_Personal_List: a reference to which Exercise is part of which Exercise_Personal_List

I'm trying to get a list of Exercises that are not yet added to a specific list. E.g. the ones that are not added to List 1. My query:

```
select * from Exercise 
where e_id not in ( 
    select e_id from Exercise_Personal_List
    where p_id_m like '1'
)
```

The result is empty. I don't see the error in the query. The correct result should be 1, 3, 5.

Btw, I'm using http://sqlfiddle.com to evaluate this stuff. It's faster for testing :)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean to be doing the following query where the second instance of `e_id` has been changed to `e_id_m`:

```
select * from Exercise 
where e_id not in ( 
    select e_id_m from Exercise_Personal_List
    where p_id_m like '1'
)
```

Comment: Naming confusion...damn. My plan was to fix the naming stuff afterwards. I should have changed it before ;) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is a little mess up in the creation - you shouldn't use `auto_increment` in the joining table:

```
CREATE TABLE Exercise_Personal_List 
(
 e_id_m int, 
 p_id_m int
);
```

And the selection should be:

```
select * from Exercise 
where e_id not in ( 
    select e_id_m as e_id from Exercise_Personal_List
    where p_id_m like '1'
)
```